# Views background not showing in Rajawali

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, rajawali

I've been trying Rajawali to develop some apps, but, while it seems pretty good, I've ran into some trouble.

The main issue is that when i call a `RajawaliActivity`, and in every other activity called after it, the background of normal Android Views do not show, including the background of the layout being used.

As normal, I am using a `RajawaliRenderer` to show the 3d models, setting the `surfaceView` of the `mRenderer`, as shown in the sample apps and the tutorials.

Has anyone encountered the same problem or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

In the manifest file set

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

for each non 3D activity.

that solved the problem for me.

courtesy https://github.com/jwoolston